TimefoldSolverAutoConfiguration does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void postProcessBeanFactory
I tried to upgrade from Optaplanner to Timefold manually(Openwrite script doesn't work for me, I follow the list of changes in pom.xml and application.properties). But I failed to start the server. The error is:
TimefoldSolverAutoConfiguration does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void postProcessBeanFactory

I tried two approaches to create the solverManager:
1.
@RestController
public class APIController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(APIController.class);

    @Autowired
    private SolverManager<MeetingSchedule, UUID> solverManager;
}




@Service
public class ScheduleSolver {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduleSolver.class);
    private static final String REQUEST_ID = "requestId";

    private final SolverManager<MeetingSchedule, UUID> solverManager;
    private SolverConfig solverConfig;

    public ScheduleSolver(SolverManager<MeetingSchedule, UUID> solverManager) {
        // Use of a solverManager may be exclusive with the use of a SolverConfig
        this.solverConfig = SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource("solverConfig.xml");
        this.solverManager = solverManager;
    }

However, both of approaches report the same error. And when I look into the TimefoldSolverAutoConfiguration, it actually doesn't implement the postProcessBeanFactory method.
Do you know what the issue is here? I have followed the guide to create solver and it worked well with Optaplanner 9.
Thanks!

It sounds to be a difference of BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor in Spring beans package. I am using Spring-beans 6.0.3 while in Spring-beans 6.1.6, there is no error. In Spring 6.1.6,  it has
@Override
 default void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
 }


Upgrading to Spring 3.2.5 fix the issue. Besides, please make sure all other dependencies like Jackson is also the same version used in Timefold.
